# How to mock intent using Mockito?

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, junit, mockito, mockk

I am attempting to mock intent inside the function I made. Here is the function below

```
fun learningUnitTest(context: Context) {
    val str = context.getString(R.string.app_name)
    val intent = Intent(context, TodoFragment::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    } // it resulting null. how to mock this?
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)

    Log.d("AA", str)
    Log.d("BB", pendingIntent.toString())
}
```

And this is my unit test file

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import com.example.todoapp.controller.worker.learningUnitTest
import io.mockk.*
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.*

class ExampleUnitTest {

    private val FAKE_STRING = "FAKE"

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockContext: Context

    @Test
    fun test_function() {
        mockkStatic(Log::class)
        mockkStatic(Intent::class)
        mockContext = mock(Context::class.java)
        every { Log.d(any(), any()) } returns 0
        `when`(mockContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .thenReturn(FAKE_STRING)
        // every { Intent("aa") } returns mockIntent // Missing mocked calls inside every { ... }
        learningUnitTest(mockContext)
        verify(mockContext, times(1)).getString(R.string.app_name)
    }
}
```

And not forgetting the dependencies which I used for testing, hopefully it has the correct version. I don't think I have to show any depedencies or any setup which are not related to the test file.

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
// Optional -- Mockito framework
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk:1.12.2'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.8.0'
```

When I ran the test, it resulting an error like this

```
Method setFlags in android.content.Intent not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setFlags in android.content.Intent not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
    at android.content.Intent.setFlags(Intent.java)
    at com.example.todoapp.controller.worker.WorkerUtilsKt.learningUnitTest(WorkerUtils.kt:97)
    at com.example.todoapp.ExampleUnitTest.test_function(ExampleUnitTest.kt:35)
```

I even tried to mock using `every` for only the Intent::class.java accessing `Intent("test")` for the code like this `every { Intent("aa") } returns mockIntent`. But it still resulting an error.